# How to check each frame if player is touching screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I check if player is touching the screen every frame? I want something similar to when you keep touch the screen in the game Geometry Dash you keep on jumping if you touch the ground. I tried this but i didn't work:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = true
}
```

and the same with touchDown function:

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
        isTouching = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = true
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = false
}
```

you can then check in your update loop

```
if isTouching == true { 
   do something 
}
else {
   do something else 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
var isTouching = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = true
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = false
}
```